# Display multiple columns in Crystal report

Tags: multiple-columns, crystal-reports-2008

My data is straightforward.  I have a count of codes, broken down by month and year. I would like to display the data as follows:

[image: multicolumn]

Can I do that in Crystal 2008?

Comment: yes you can do in crystal reports

Comment: How?  I have only been able to group the data into one column.

Comment: you can use cross tab functionality to accomplish this task

Comment: Place date as the columns and data in the rows and summary data as the summation part.